# PDO SELECT only selecting first in foreach loop

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to select multiple products from my database and inserting the id into another table.

I have tried doing as below and if I just echo `$name`, `$_POST["txtMaterial"][$key]` and `$_POST["txtSize"][$key]` before the query, I get all selected names, materials and sizes, but when I bind the values in the query, I only get the first one.

```
    foreach($_POST["txtName"] as $key => $name){

      $sQuery = $db->prepare('SELECT id FROM products WHERE name = :sName AND material = :sMaterial AND size = :sSize');
      $sQuery->bindValue(':sName', $name);
      $sQuery->bindValue(':sMaterial', $_POST["txtMaterial"][$key]);
      $sQuery->bindValue(':sSize', $_POST["txtSize"][$key]);
      $sQuery->execute();
      $aOrders = $sQuery->fetchAll();

      foreach($aOrders as $aOrder){
        echo print_r($aOrders);
      }
}
```

The print_r of `$aOrders` is this:

```
"Array
(
    [id] => 174
)
1"
```

Which is the first id that I need. Can anyone help me out how to get all the id's?

var_dump of `$_POST["txtName"]` before the foreach:

```
"array(50) {
  [0]=>
  string(0) ""
  [1]=>
  string(6) "BACURI"
  [2]=>
  string(0) ""
  [3]=>
  string(0) ""
  [4]=>
  string(0) ""
  [5]=>
  string(0) ""
  [6]=>
  string(0) ""
  [7]=>
  string(0) ""
  [8]=>
  string(0) ""
  [9]=>
  string(0) ""
  [10]=>
  string(0) ""
  [11]=>
  string(0) ""
  [12]=>
  string(0) ""
  [13]=>
  string(0) ""
  [14]=>
  string(0) ""
  [15]=>
  string(0) ""
  [16]=>
  string(0) ""
  [17]=>
  string(0) ""
  [18]=>
  string(0) ""
  [19]=>
  string(0) ""
  [20]=>
  string(0) ""
  [21]=>
  string(0) ""
  [22]=>
  string(0) ""
  [23]=>
  string(0) ""
  [24]=>
  string(0) ""
  [25]=>
  string(0) ""
  [26]=>
  string(0) ""
  [27]=>
  string(0) ""
  [28]=>
  string(0) ""
  [29]=>
  string(6) "CAJARI"
  [30]=>
  string(0) ""
  [31]=>
  string(0) ""
  [32]=>
  string(0) ""
  [33]=>
  string(0) ""
  [34]=>
  string(0) ""
  [35]=>
  string(0) ""
  [36]=>
  string(0) ""
  [37]=>
  string(0) ""
  [38]=>
  string(0) ""
  [39]=>
  string(0) ""
  [40]=>
  string(0) ""
  [41]=>
  string(0) ""
  [42]=>
  string(0) ""
  [43]=>
  string(0) ""
  [44]=>
  string(0) ""
  [45]=>
  string(0) ""
  [46]=>
  string(0) ""
  [47]=>
  string(0) ""
  [48]=>
  string(0) ""
  [49]=>
  string(0) ""
}
"
```

var_dump of `$_POST["txtMaterial"]` before foreach:

```
"array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "3"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "2"
}
"
```

var_dump of `$_POST["txtSize"]` before foreach:

```
"array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "20"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "4"
}
"
```

Comment: Use `print_r` on `$aOrders`.. `$aOrder` will only ever have 1 row.

Comment: It returns the exact same for $aOrders

Comment: On the second iteration `$aOrders` has `174` again? Can you output values and verify they are correct?

Comment: There is no second iteration, that is the issue. All it shows is the first value and then nothing else, although it does exist before doing the query.

Comment: What exists before the query? If you comment out all the PDO code and do `echo $name . PHP_EOL;` you get all the names back? If the remove comments then run again you only get one `$name` return??

Comment: @caroline4321 Could you `var_dump($_POST["txtName"])` before the first loop? and show that to us? As well as `$_POST["txtMaterial"]` and `$_POST["txtSize"]`

Comment: The foreach loop `foreach($_POST["txtName"] as $key => $name)` is written before the query, and if i do `$name` before that, I get all the names back. With `echo $name . PHP_EOL` I only get the first again

Comment: @Serghei Leonenco I have added it to the question

Comment: Do I need to add more details about the code?

Comment: Does your DB product table contain an empty name field?

Comment: @Serghei Leonenco No, it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According provided information you getting one record `ID` because  the only time when you prepare your statement and it is not empty is the second iteration of the loop. You have only 2 keys in associated arrays `txtMaterial` and `txtSize`, the any next ones will return null. Take a look here:

**First loop**
Your prepared statement will looks like this:

```
SELECT id FROM products WHERE name = "" AND material = 3 AND size = 20
```

this statement will return an `empty` array

**Second loop**

```
SELECT id FROM products WHERE name = "BACURI" AND material = 2 AND size = 4
```

This will end up with result what you get. Array with one record `ID = 174`.

**Any next iteration...**

```
SELECT id FROM products WHERE name = "" AND material = NULL AND size = NULL
```

This will return an `empty` array

**Here is the test:**

```
$name = ["", "BACURI", ""];
$material = ["3", "2"];
$size = ["20", "4"];

foreach($name as $key => $val){
    echo "\n";
    var_dump($val);
    var_dump($material[$key]);
    var_dump($size[$key]);
}
```

**Output**

```
string(0) ""
string(1) "3"
string(2) "20"

string(6) "BACURI"
string(1) "2"
string(1) "4"

string(0) ""
NULL
NULL
```

Hope it helps.